# Haskell's Foreign.C equivalent of C's ampersand operator (&)

Tags: pointers, haskell, ffi, ampersand

As you will know, for any identifier `ident` in C, you can write `&ident` to obtain the memory location (pointer) to `ident`, regardless of whether that location is on the heap or on the stack. Whilst working with C types, it is often helpful to have access to this functionality.

Is there an equivalent operation in Haskell in the FFI?

Comment: Think of every foreign ref you have as a pointer.  You already have their addresses.  Unless you are asking about the addresses of the addresses, in which case, Haskell doesn't work like C enough to support that (Haskell reserves the right to move your data around -- and GHC does, quite a lot)

Comment: Perhaps you should be asking a higher level question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was playing around with OpenCLRaw, and am trying to compile (linking *seems* to work alright).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a C identifier you're importing into Haskell, you can convert it to a pointer to that address via the "&" syntax in [FFI declarations](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/haskell/ffi/ffi/ffise4.html#x7-150004), like so:

```
foreign import ccall "&" bar :: Ptr CInt
```

Typically this is quite a rare thing to do, as almost everything you import is already a pointer.

Haskell values themselves may also be turned into pointers, using [stable pointers](http://lambda.haskell.org/hp-tmp/docs/2011.2.0.0/ghc-doc/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/Foreign-StablePtr.html), to ensure they're unaffected by the garbage collector.